# Change URL of iFrame with jQuery button click?

Tags: jquery, iframe, youtube

I'm trying to figure out how to change the video within this iframe upon clicking the blue button.
So, in other words, clicking the blue button will change the video that's playing in the iframe.

If anyone has ideas of how to do this, please let me know...

http://jsfiddle.net/69nj13nL/

HTML

```
<div id="stage">
            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/e-ORhEE9VVg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<br>

<div id="button">Click me</div>
```

CSS

```
#button{
    background:blue;
    cursor:pointer;
    width:200px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    color:white;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).on('click', '#button', function(event) {


});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this:

```
$( "#button" ).click(function() {
    $("#stage > iframe").attr("src", "http://www.wp.pl");
});
```

Where `http://www.wp.pl` is just a link for you to replace. You can always try to do it with somekind of loop to get more songs.

Comment: Thank you. That seems like it should work, but oddly, there is still a problem. Not sure what's going on... I'm tinkering with it still, but of course if you can spot the solution please do let me in on it. http://jsfiddle.net/69nj13nL/2/

Comment: nevermind... I hadn't activated jQuery on that jsfiddle. This works perfectly, then. Thank you again!